# How to change the width of UIButton within its @IBDesignable class?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, storyboard

This is my class:

```
@IBDesignable class WLButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var width: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            frame.size.width = width
        }
    }
}
```

This class doesn't change the button's width in Storyboard. Why?

Comment: Sizes should be handled by constraints

Comment: I know, but I need to add manually some subviews to this button. And hence its size is variable. At the end I will need to change this, and I do not know why. Any ideas?

Comment: In didSet you can get width constraint, change it's constant and call updateConstraints() method. But it will work if you'll set width constraint in IB